# Decimal to binary using functions

Tags: python

I am attempting to take an input via a function and return the number in binary. This is my code so far and I am not quite sure how to proceed. For the comments, I understand `bin()` is a built in function but I need to create my own way of outputting binary.

Also note: I have updated the code and I have come as far as getting all the 1's to add correctly to output but I'm not sure how to add the 0's.

```
def dectobin(x):
    e=0
    output=""
    p=0
    while p <= x:
        p=2**e
        e+=1
        if 2**e >= x:
            x = x - 2**(e-1)
            e=0
            p=0
            p=2**e
            output+=str(1)
        if 2**e > x:
            p = p//2
            if p > x:
                p=p//2
                output+=0
            x = x = p
            output+=1
    return output

print(dectobin(99))
```

Comment: Python already has a builtin function for this called `bin()`

Comment: Is this some kind of homework that you are doing? Because, python has ready made functions to do that.
bin(x) --> gives you binary of x

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? What *input* are you using to test it. what does the function return for that input, and what did you expect it to return? Do you suspect any part of it?

Comment: Guys maybe he just wants to practice and figure if he can do it himself. Maybe thats why bin() wouldnt be of use to him

Comment: @jordanm I need to make my own binary function

Comment: Ok @Kamal thats what I thought

Comment: @Kamal please list rules of engagement. Are there any other restrictions? Are you allowed to use bitwise operators?

Comment: @Gillespie You know gill, I would be able to answer that if I knew what a bitwise operator was. I just need to create this using a function, while loop and simple math equations and the return operators, also if and elif and else operators if required.

Comment: You can use http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit to visualize the execution of your code. you have your logic wrong somewhere . this also might help - [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Is the input always an integer, or are other types (like floats or strings) allowed?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is in-built in Python. `bin` is the name. Here's the help message:

> Help on built-in function bin in module builtins:
>
> bin(number, /)
>       Return the binary representation of an integer.
>
> ```
> >>> bin(2796202)
> '0b1010101010101010101010'
> ```

---

Here's what I came up with for my own solution:

```
def binary(n):
  if n == 0:
    return '0'
  orders = []
  i = 1
  while i <= n:
    orders.append(i)
    i *= 2
  orders = orders[::-1]  # decreasing powers of n

  # for each `order` we need a 0 or a 1
  b = ''
  for o in orders:
    if o <= n:
      b += '1'
      n -= o
    else:
      b += '0'
  return b
```

And my check was (inefficient, but ¯_(ツ)_/¯):

```
assert(all(bin(n)[2:] == binary(n) for n in range(1025)))
```

Comment: Thanks, however I need to create my own way of outputting binary in a function

Comment: @Kamal I've added my own solution. Yours has too many variable for me to work out what's happening.